# Orthogonal 3-d vectors with prime number length

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

Is it true a proposition that always exists 3-d $\mathbf{v}$ vector of length equal a prime number $n$ ($n>5$) with integer (but non-zero) components and we can always find other 3-d vector $\mathbf{w}$ of equal length and integer components which is orthogonal to the previous one?

So far I have only partial empirical evidence.. Examples

Length

7 :  $\mathbf{v}$= [2  3   6]=[$2$ $3$ $(2*3)$],   $\mathbf{w}$=[6  2  -3]

11:   $\mathbf{v}$= [2 6 9]=[$2$ $(2*3)$ $(3*3)$],   $\mathbf{w}$= [9 -6 2]

13:  $\mathbf{v}$= [3 4 12]=[$(3$ $(2*2)$ $(2*2*3)$],  $\mathbf{w}$=[4 -12 3]

17:  $\mathbf{v}$= [8 9 12]= [ $(2*2*2)$ $(3*3)$ $(2*2*3)$], $\mathbf{w}$=[9 8 -12]

19:  $\mathbf{v}$= [1 6 18]=[$1$ $(2*3)$ $(2*3*3)$], $\mathbf{w}$=[18 -6 1]

.. *(please add new examples if you know)*

& 
if it is true **why** is so ?

Comment: Related to this question is https://oeis.org/A267651

Comment: The [law of small numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasty_generalization#Alternative_names) in action, I guess. Look at the very next prime number, 23. There are 3 (up to permutations) vectors with that length: $(3,6,22),\,(3,14,18)$ and $(6,13,18)$. Good luck trying to transform any of these to its orthogonal by permuting and negating its components.

Comment: Yes, from 7 to 19 we have only combinations of 1,2 and 3 but the pattern doesn't continue for bigger numbers. However interesting is that always, it seems, vector can be found for prime number length and orthogonal vector to it. Probably some hidden pattern lies however behind it.

Comment: Yeah, possibly there is a whole infinite family of such primes.

Comment: All primes, might be assumed ?

Comment: Did not I just show that 23 is **not** such prime?

Comment: I mean, there is a vector and its ortho-vector - numbers of both can be different.

Comment: Then why are they the same (up to permutation) in all your examples? Of course, if the only requirement to **w** is to be orthogonal with **v**, there are plenty of such vectors, no matter what.

Comment: Because I had stopped before 20 :) Now I know solution also for 23 and 29. Maybe you know where are tables for such vectors ? Maybe someone collected them for much bigger n..

Comment: There is no need to collect anything. PowersRepresentations[n^2, 3, 2] in Wolfram Mathematica would generate such a table for you.

Comment: I guess other computer algebra systems must contain similar functionality, it's just that I'm not familiar with those.